# ReSharper CLI Global Tools generate .editorconfig and .DotSettings

Tags: command-line-interface, resharper

I am currently using the latest version of the https://www.nuget.org/packages/JetBrains.ReSharper.GlobalTools

```
dotnet tool install --global JetBrains.ReSharper.GlobalTools --version 2023.1.0
```

I wonder if it is possible to generate a .editorconfig and a .DotSettings file from the CLI that includes the ReSharper settings. I am unable to find any information about this in the docs, but meaby I am looking wrong.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you want to achieve? Both `.editorconfig` and `.DotSettings` are just plain text files - you can create them like any other text file depending on your platform (e. g. `"[*]\`r\`nend_of_line=lf" > .editorconfig` in PowerShell Core)

Comment: Yes, I would like to generate these 2 files from the CLI in a .ps1 or .sh script so that they get automatically generated whenever the user sets up a new environment. This just helps with CI. They shouldn't be empty but contain the default resharper and dotnet settings.

Comment: Then I see no need for `JetBrains.ReSharper.GlobalTools` - just use `"[*]\`r\`nend_of_line=lf" > .editorconfig` or whatever you want to use as default

Comment: But an empty .editorconfig file would not contain any settings to adjust. I would like it to contain the default settings from the .editorconfig file that gets generated by ReSharper, but I'm not sure how to get those

Comment: Ah okay, that's why I asked because this is unclear in your question  well, AFAIK the R# Command Line Tools (aka R# CLT or _Global Tools_) don't support this (yet). For `.editorconfig`, you could use `dotnet new editorconfig`. For `.DotSettings`, I think you have to maintain a template and copy this into the new environment

Comment: Aah okay, well that is unfortunate. But thank you for informing me about this.